# show only one type of user in forms using django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create an appointment app using Django

but when I add the form it show me all the users

how can i change that to only one type of user

and make the user who register the appointment him self

this is my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('paitent', 'paitent'), ('Doctor', 'Doctor'), ('reception', 'reception'), ('temporary', 'temporary'))
    STATUS_CHOICES_2 = (('yes', 'yes'), ('no', 'no'))
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='paitent')
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES_2, default='yes')

    def is_doctor(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'Doctor':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_paitent(self):
        if self.type_of_user == 'paitent':
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Appointement_P(models.Model):
    user_ho_add = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_ho_add_appointement')
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='paitent_app')
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctor_app')
    date = models.Field(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
```

and this is my fomrs.py

```
class AppointementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointement_P
        fields = ('doctor', 'date', 'start_time',)
```

and this is my fucntion in the views.py

```
def create_appointement_p(request):
    user = User()
    form_appointement = AppointementForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.user.is_paitent():
            form_appointement = AppointementForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_appointement.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointement added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')
            
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement1.html',)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointement_D"))
    return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement1.html',{'form':form_appointement})
```

and this is the html file

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
            {{ form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            <button>
                ok
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

- the problem is in the doctoral field, it show me all the user how can I change that to only users that have a type of doctors
- how can I make the `user_ho_add` automatically the one ho register this appointment?
- how can I make the end time of the appointment the start_time + 30 min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering the `doctor` field you can customize it in you `ModelForm` class, like this:

```py
# import your User model first

class AppointementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user='Doctor'))
    class Meta:
        model = Appointement_P
        fields = ('doctor', 'date', 'start_time',)
```

Then for filling the `user_ho_add` field, just add the user before saving the `form_app` instance, like this:

```py
def create_appointement_p(request):
    ...
            if form_appointement.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
                form_app.user = request.user  # user added here
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointement added')
    ...
```

**Bonus tip**: for the `is_paitent` and `is_doctor` methods, you can simply return the comparison, since the result is already a boolean, like this:

```py
def is_doctor(self):
    return self.type_of_user == 'Doctor'

def is_paitent(self):
    return self.type_of_user == 'paitent'
```

#### UPDATE

As requested in the comment, for adding `end_time = start_time + 30min` you first need to import the `timedelta` class from the `datetime` library.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
# your other imports
...
def create_appointement_p(request):
    ...
            if form_appointement.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
                form_app.user = request.user  # user added here
                form_app.end_time = form_app.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)  # end_time added here
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointement added')
    ...
```

**Bonus tip 2**: If you're using Django 3.1 (or above) you can use the `models.TextChoices` class to create a cleaner way to reference your choices, like this:

```py
class TypeOfUser(models.TextChoices):
    # REFERENCE_VALUE = 'string to save in the field', 'string to display (supports translation)'
    PAITENT = 'paitent', 'Patient'
    DOCTOR = 'doctor', 'Doctor'
    RECEPTION = 'reception', 'Reception'
    TEMPORARY = 'temporary', 'Temporary'

class AllowdToTakeAppointement(models.TextChoices):
    YES = 'yes', 'Yes'
    NO = 'no', 'No'

class User(AbstractUser):
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=TypeOfUser, default=TypeOfUser.PAITENT)
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=AllowdToTakeAppointement.choices, default=AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES
    )

    def is_doctor(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.DOCTOR

    def is_paitent(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.PAITENT
```

Then you can import the `TypeOfUser` class for your `AppointementForm` class:

```py
# import your User model and TypeOfUser

class AppointementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    class Meta:
        model = Appointement_P
        fields = ('doctor', 'date', 'start_time',)
```

Comment: it work thank you very much, if you could please help me with the last question how I can make the end_time = start_time + 30 min and it will be added automatically

Comment: I'll update my answer, with another bonus tip in case you are using Django 3.1 or above

Comment: thank you very much for the tip it really helped me

Comment: Glad I can help. I just stumble upon the `models.TextChoices` class a couples of days ago, and I found it pretty useful. Another thing I would suggest is correct some typos (like 'patient' instead of 'paitent', 'appointment' instead of 'appointement') to make your code cleaner (as long as this isn't in a production environment yet and doesn't contain data you can't restore because it will probably wipe the tables and create new ones). Since English is not my native language, I often google some words to check them before writing them in my code :P.

Comment: Thank you very much
Even my English is not my native language That's why I am struggling with it
I will try to work with all your advice
Thanks again